# Preprocessor in visual studio 2010-c++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c-preprocessor

In .cpp file I use a macro `mmData1`.I searched in the project and see  that this macro is defined in several files.(I.e. there are several .h files which have the line `#define mmData1`)

I want to know if there is a capability in VS10 to check from which file the preprocessor takes the macro value

Comment: I believe you can go to the location where you _use_ the macro and right-click on the macro name. The popup menu has "Go To Definition" and "Go To Declaration" options. One of those should work, I don't remember which.

Comment: @Blastfurnace-it doesn`t work "symbol mmData1 could not be located"

Comment: @Blastfurnace nah, intellisense doesn't do much in this case. You probably get a list of definitions, not the one it uses.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore:  I have found that it does go to the correct definition each time (perhaps I have just been lucky).

Comment: @MarkWilkins you have, don't rely on it.

Comment: Do you want only a VS tool? Are you opened to other toolkits that can do that?

Comment: Yeah, VS2010 is a lot better in this respect than previous editions...  But I'm still a fan of [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/)

Comment: do you have some build-time warnings about duplicate definitions?
Try to comment out some of the defines.  You'll soon find out, which is the used one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Intellisense does not know then there is no direct way. However, there are indirect ways. Say your macro name is `SOME_MACRO`

1. After each instance of `#define SOME_MACRO` put `#error Defined here`, then right click the source file and choose `Compile`. If compiler returns an error remove the directive that raises it and compile again. The last instance of this error will tail the definition visible in the source.
2. Make each directive defining `SOME_MACRO` define it as something else and then, in the source file, add these lines after all includes:

   ```
   #define STRINGIZE(x) STRINGIZE2(x)
   #define STRINGIZE2(x) #x
   #pragma message("SOME_MACRO is expanded as: " STRINGIZE(SOME_MACRO))
   ```

   Compile the source file; you should see the value in the build log.
3. Less intrusive way: put those lines after each `#define SOME_MACRO`

   ```
   #pragma push_macro("STRINGIZE")
   #pragma push_macro("STRINGIZE2")
   #define STRINGIZE(x) STRINGIZE2(x)
   #define STRINGIZE2(x) #x
   #pragma message("Defining at " __FILE__ ":" STRINGIZE(__LINE__))
   #pragma pop_macro("STRINGIZE")
   #pragma pop_macro("STRINGIZE2")
   ```

   Or, if you don't need the line number:

   ```
   #pragma message("Defining at " __FILE__)
   ```

   Compile the file. Looking at build log you should be able to tell the order of `SOME_MACRO` definitions.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to see exactly what the preprocessor is doing is to [inspect its output directly.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)  Intellisense is helpful but often does not match what the compiler understands.

Answer (score 0):

A simple trick I always use is to **redefine** the macro at the line you want to check. When you compile the code, the preprocessor will complain and tell you where the previous definition was.

Example:

test.cpp contains:

```
#include "test.h"

int main()
{
  #define SOMEMACRO 1
  return 0;
}
```

test.h contains:

```
#define SOMEMACRO 2
int foo();
```

when compiling test.cpp, I get this error message:

```
test.cpp:5:0: warning: "SOMEMACRO" redefined [enabled by default]
In file included from test.cpp:1:0:
test.h:1:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
```

I tested on GCC, but Visual Studio does the same thing.